# How to execute InstaPy on Google Chrome newest version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, instapy

The OS used is Windows 10.

I am trying to execute some methods in InstaPy module on chrome browser but the error given off when I run the code is the following:

-- selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line --

I have tried to work around the problem by importing binary_path from instapy_chromedriver.
`from instapy_chromedriver import binary_path`

After running the following line of code, it turns out that only Chrome versions from 71 to 75 are supported

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=binary_path)`

So the only solution would be to downgrade the current Chrome version (Version 92) that I am using, however I do not believe that this is actually worthy to be named a solution. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any clue in the web that would enable me to think of a workaround.

Your ideas and/or advices will be greatly appreciated.